# AngularJS + Bootstrap Pagination

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have all my data in multiple JSON:

```
http://localhost:3000/images?page=1

http://localhost:3000/images?page=2

http://localhost:3000/images?page=3
...
```

So with AngularJS I would like a pagination with Next/Prev.

Something like:
http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/

But with multiple JSON in input and a Controller.

Thanks!

Example of JSON: **"pageCount":7,"itemCount":68**

```
{"images":[{"_id":"542e57a709d2d60000c93953","name":"image1","url":"http://www.syll.com","__v":0},{"_id":"542e58e19d237e5b790f4db2","name":"image154","url":"www.rufyge.com"},{"_id":"542e58e19d237e5b790f4db3","name":"image45784","url":"http://www.test.com"},{"_id":"542eb5bbe26bca641c676ec9","name":"image1","url":"http://www.sl.com","__v":0},{"_id":"542eff1197896530323371b2","name":"image1","url":"http://www.sl.com","__v":0},{"_id":"542f0514b96a17781a5de9ef","name":"image1","url":"http://www.sl.com","__v":0},{"_id":"542f0b618101e35037651a7b","name":"image1","url":"http://www.sl.com","__v":0},{"_id":"543247b7d78ae2dc6a73c4eb","name":"image1","url":"http://www.sl.com","__v":0},{"_id":"543249050fcae2f082ca3e70","name":"imageOCR1","url_image":"http://meta-e.aib.uni-linz.ac.at/ocr/images/biographie_ocr.gif","__v":0},{"_id":"543249050fcae2f082ca3e71","name":"imageOCR2","url_image":"http://www.textcreationpartnership.org/files/2012/02/ocr.jpg","__v":0}],"pageCount":7,"itemCount":68}
```

Comment: you can use grid module to achieve it. check this http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/6 .

Comment: Thanks! But what I am looking for is Next/Prev, not page 1,2,3 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your GETs in an angular service or factory like this:

```
angular.module('pages',[]).factory('Pages', function($http) {  
    return {
       getPage: function(pageNum, callback) {
           $http.get('/images?page=' + pageNum).success(function(data, status) {
               callback(data, status);
           });
        }
    }
});
```

Then inject the service into your controller.  Here is an edit to your jsfiddle with this approach stubbed out: http://jsfiddle.net/ef0d9zuk/1/

Hope it helps.